# angularjs ui-select disable dropdown list and make it only searchable

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, ui-select

Here is the plunker for my issue: http://plnkr.co/edit/9DsLidTZR7RJDEq6PW0H?p=preview

I would like to make the dropdown menu searchable only: the use only sees the list of the dropdown items ONLY when the user starts to type in, and only the corresponding items which contain the typed word or letters should appear in the list, otherwise the list is not shown at all.

```
<ui-select ng-model="person.selectedValue" theme="select2" ng-disabled="disabled" style="min-width: 300px;" title="Choose a person">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select a person in the list or search his name/age...">{{$select.selected.value.name}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="person.value as (key, person) in peopleObj | filter: {'value':$select.search}">
      <div ng-bind-html="person.value.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
      <small>
        email: {{person.value.email}}
        age: <span ng-bind-html="''+person.value.age | highlight: $select.search"></span>
      </small>
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-style` and modify the choices `ul` height property. Don't think there is any OOB solution in the library

```
<ui-select-choices ng-style="($select.search != '')? {'height' : 'auto'}: {'height' : '0px'}" repeat="person.value as (key, person) in peopleObj | filter: {'value':$select.search}">
        <div ng-bind-html="person.value.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
        <small>
        email: {{person.value.email}}
        age: <span ng-bind-html="''+person.value.age | highlight: $select.search"></span>
      </small>
</ui-select-choices>
```

Let us know.